# Creating dynamic button and its event handler

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, eventhandler

I am trying to use dynamics buttons and events. When I clicked static button and I showed dynamic button. But When I clicked dynamic button I didn't work dinamikButon_Click event. What is my wrong? Sorry my language. Thx in advance.

Default.aspx.cs is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWebApplication
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    int i = 1;
    Button dinamikButon;
    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

    }

    protected void btnStatik_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        dinamikButon = new Button
        {
            Text = "Dinamik" + i,
            ID = "btnDinamik" + i,
            CommandArgument = "commandArgument",
            CommandName = "commandName"

        };
        dinamikButon.Click += dinamikButon_Click;
        panel1.Controls.Add( dinamikButon );
        i++;
    }

    void dinamikButon_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        Label1.Text = "Merhaba dinamik butondan geliyorum.";
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that's because when the page posts back the button doesn't exist. You have to create the buttons on page Load or PreInit. Microsoft suggests [**PreInit**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit(v=vs.140).aspx) `You can dynamically set a master page or a theme for the requested page, and create dynamic controls.`

```
    int i = 1;
    Button dinamikButon;
    private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateButton();
        }
    }

    protected void btnStatik_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        CreateButton();
    }

    private void CreateButton()
    {
        dinamikButon = new Button
        {
            Text = "Dinamik" + i,
            ID = "btnDinamik" + i,
            CommandArgument = "commandArgument",
            CommandName = "commandName"

        };
        dinamikButon.Click += dinamikButon_Click;
        panel1.Controls.Add( dinamikButon );
        i++;
    }
```

**Update:**

Do do what you've asked now we have to specify that the button has been created using either viewstate, querystring or session.

In this example I'll use a session:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Created"] != null)
            {
                CreateButton();
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateButton()
    {
        dinamikButon = new Button
        {
            Text = "Dinamik" + i,
            ID = "btnDinamik" + i,
            CommandArgument = "commandArgument",
            CommandName = "commandName"

        };

        Panel1.Controls.Add(dinamikButon);
        dinamikButon.Click += dinamikButon_Click;
        i++;
        Session["Created"] = "true";
    }

    private void dinamikButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your action here
    }
```

Comment: Firstly thx, but it is not working correctly. Because when I run the program, static and dynamic buttons showing on screen. And then When I clicked static button, it creating and showing other dynamic button.

Comment: Thanks @prospector. In little time, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

### To fill value in "Label1" control using dynamic button

### Default.aspx

```
                <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicCtrl._Default" %>

                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head runat="server">
                    <title></title>

                    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                        function dynamicevnt() {
                            document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = "Merhaba dinamik butondan geliyorum.";
                            return false;
                        }
                    </script>

                </head>
                <body>
                    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnStatik" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="btnStatik_Click" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>

                    </div>
                    </form>
                </body>
                </html>
```

### Default.aspx.cs

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.UI;
            using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

            namespace DynamicCtrl
            {
                public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
                {

                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                    }
                    protected void btnStatik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        CreateButton();
                    }
                    private void CreateButton()
                    {
                        int i = 1;
                        Button dinamikButon = new Button();
                        dinamikButon.Text = "Dinamik" + i;
                        dinamikButon.ID = "btnDinamik" + i;
                        dinamikButon.OnClientClick = "return dynamicevnt();";
                        dinamikButon.Click += new EventHandler(dinamikButon_Click);
                        panel1.Controls.Add(dinamikButon);
                        i++;
                    }
                    protected void dinamikButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "Merhaba dinamik butondan geliyorum.";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I know how can i making use javascript. But I must not use js. Thx.